# Keep iframe content to display source html, but have source page to redirect

Tags: html, redirect, iframe

I have an iframe that displays content from html page (within the same domain), let say iframe content is `mydomain.com/page1.html`.

Obviously, I want the content of the `page1.html` displayed within iframe.

However, I would like have this file (`page1.html`) be redirected to my main site (`mydomain.com`) when the whole URL (`mydomain.com/page1.html`) is typed in the browser - without changing it inside iframe.

Is this something even doable? I will appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: I think you're looking for this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.postMessage

Comment: @alfasin I thought he might mean something like that too, but reading the question again, I believe the OP simply wants to prevent the frame from being reached as an orphaned part of the website, and if it is reached in that way, then to redirect back to the full home page.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, from what you wrote, it sounds like you want this to happen:

- mydomain.com/page1.html typed into browser redirects to mydomain.com/
- mydomain.com/page1.html loaded into iframe does not redirect but
  stays in the iframe unchanged

You can add this very simple script to `page1.html` to accomplish this:

```
<script>
if (top == self)
    location.href = '/';
</script>
```

Warning: Do NOT add this script to your domain's default home page or else you will cause an infinite loading loop.

### Self-Contained Example

Home page `index.html` contains:

```
<p>This is the home page, containing a frame.</p>
<iframe src="page1.html"></iframe>
```

Frame page `page1.html` contains:

```
<script>
if (top == self)
    location.href = '/';
</script>
<p>
This page will display in a frame only.
Loading it directly as the main page will redirect
the user to the default home page of the
website.
</p>
```

### Result

Loading the website's main domain will show the text "This is the home page, containing a frame." as well as the frame, containing "This page will display in a frame only...."

Directly entering the website's main domain followed by `/page1.html` will immediately redirect back to the main domain's home page itself.